# EF Core: Interpreting Guid.Empty as null in optional foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a `Guid` foreign key that is configured as `.IsRequired(false)`. I want to be able to set this foreign key to `Guid.Empty` to say that it is null.

But when I do try to use it like that, the following query is generated:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Error: Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@p0='d644704c-7735-47a6-cea5-08d87bf854bb' (DbType = String), @p1='2017-07-12T14:33:10' (DbType = String), @p2='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' (DbType = String), @p3='2020-10-29T10:50:01' (DbType = String), @p4='scan1' (Nullable = false) (Size = 5), @p5='0' (DbType = String), @p6='V;Potential;E' (Nullable = false) (Size = 13)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO "DataArrays" ("Id", "CreatedOn", "DataSetId", "LastModifiedOn", "Name", "Order", "Unit")  
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6);
```

It tries to set `@p2` to `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`, which results in the database returning a foreign key constraint error because it is not a valid key.

How do I configure EF in such a way that `Guid.Empty` is interpreted as null?

Comment: Make it nullable?

Comment: @user743414 Without making it nullable. I want `Guid.Empty` to mean null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ValueConverters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) for this. There are a number of built-in converters available, but not one that fits your needs. You'll have to create a custom converter by inheriting the `ValueConverter` class.

Comment: I've seem to have gotten a bit further by creating a `ValueConverter` that turns it into a `Guid?`, but this now results in a `NOT NULL constraint failed`, even though I've explicitly set `.IsRequired(false)`. Could you provide more details on how this should work?

Comment: I just successfully tested following converter. Are you sure the column in the database is actually nullable? Perhaps a migration that hasn't been applied yet?
`
internal class GuidToNullConverter : ValueConverter<Guid?, Guid?>
    {
        public GuidToNullConverter(
            ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null)
            : base(x => x == Guid.Empty ? default : x, x => x, mappingHints)
        {
        }
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is a bit hidden in the comment of @Thomas Ducheyne' s answer.
First use a ValueConverter that converts Guid.Empty into null:

```
internal class GuidToNullConverter : ValueConverter<Guid?, Guid?>
{
    public GuidToNullConverter(ConverterMappingHints? mappingHints = null)
        : base(x => x == Guid.Empty ? default : x, x => x, mappingHints)
    {
    }
}
```

You can then use this converter in your DbContext class as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.YourGuidProperty)
        .HasConversion(new GuidToNullConverter());
}
```